# Adding subcomponent to component in React Native

Tags: react-native, components, state

Somewhere in my code I use the .map function to create an array of  components, and I update state with those components. The ListItems are then rendered in the return() function.

My question is how I can add a subcomponent to a component later? Like in the code below, the 'Badge' component would need be there initially but added later to display that there is a new unread message from this user. How to do this?

```
  var chatsWithUsersInfo = userInfo.map((message, index) => (
    <ListItem key={index} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GiftedChat', { otherPersonUserId: message.userId }) }>
     <Avatar rounded source={{ uri: message.profilePictureURI }} />


     <Badge
     status="success"
     containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', top: -4, right: -4 }}
     />

     <ListItem.Content>
       <ListItem.Title>{message.name}</ListItem.Title>
     </ListItem.Content>
   </ListItem>
  ))
  setChats(chatsWithUsersInfo)
```

How can I add a subcomponent to this array of ListItem components later?

Answer (score 1):

React has some good docs on conditional rendering https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

```
{ message?.unread
  ? <Badge />
  : null
}
```

PS, you're going to have a hard time managing this by putting your list of React components inside state.

Your list of components `chatsWithUsersInfo` is derived from `userInfo`, so compute it in the render function (or function body/return for functional components). Let React handle the reactivity.

```
const Chats = (props) => {
  return <Container>
    {userInfo.map(...)}
  <Container />;
}
```

Reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state

Edit: Update to your question.

Consider these two equivalent components

```
const Comp = ({}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Markup is derived from state :+1:
  return <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
    {count && <Label>{count}</Label>}
  </Button>;
};

const Comp = ({}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Let's set the Label component on state
  const [Label, setLabel] = useState(null);

  // Now we need to add a redundant render every
  // time count updates so we can update the Label
  // component and render again!
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count) setLabel(<Label>{count}<Label/>);
  }, [count]);

  return <Button onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
    {Label}
  </Button>;
};
```

Comment: Ok if there is no other way to update a single ListItem component with the badge then I guess conditional rendering is the way to go. Do you by any chance know how to create a component and have its prop linked to state? Like 'radius' in my other question--right now it only takes the state value when it is created but it is not updated when the state value changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480668/create-component-object-whose-prop-is-linked-to-state

Comment: Yes, don't put React components on state. The return statement in a component should contain all the rules of how to render the UI based on any possible state/props. Don't put component in state.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Will put needed variables in state then and run a for-loop within the render/return function. React isn't very clear on why you should keep the bare minimum in state but I guess it's more efficient in handling the rendering within the actual render/return function..